# CloudBees and Custom Error Pages

Tags: java, web.xml, cloudbees, custom-error-pages, paas

Does CloudBees allow you to define custom error pages beyond what you can to with a traditional Java web app (via `web.xml`)?

For instance, if a CloudBees app-cell instance goes down due to infrastructure issues, is there a type of exception it will throw that can be caught and handled by the application backend? Or a special exception/error page that can be defined if the app runs out of memory/PermGen? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error page in web.xml are used to render application errors, and suppose the application server is up-and-running. Container errors / maintenance / shutdown can't benefit from application resources by nature.

If an app-cell instance goes down, your application has no chance to throw any exception as it will have been killed with the app-cell. An OOM error will automatically trigger an application restart. Generally speaking, the platform will ensure you always have one instance running.